# Crystal report command fields not appearing when using Pivot on Temp table values

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have created some SQL which runs perfectly fine in SQL manager. As soon as I put the sql into a crystal report, none of the fields appear in the command area.

I have narrowed down the issue to the use of a Pivot in the query. The pivot is on a field which is using a field from a temporary table. As soon as I change the temp table field to a field from a standard db table, the fields appear under the commands area.

I can't however figure out why the pivot/crystal is behaving this way when using a temp table field. Has anyone come across this issue before? How did you resolve it?

I will add the query asap, just thought maybe some had had this issue before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved.
The issue was as stated with the Pivot using a value from a temp table.

To resolve the problem I wrapped the Calculation with error checking. Looks like Crystal reports was doing some code checking which SQL wasnt.

`Example Below:`

Below didn't work

Value/temp table Value AS NEW_VALUE

Below did work

```
ISNULL(Value/NULLIF(Temp Table Value,0),0) AS NEW_VALUE
```